# Workaround for AdvancedDataGrid flicker in Flex Hero 4.5.0.19786

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

Since I updated to the latest build of Flex Hero (4.5.0.19786) AdvancedDataGrids flicker in design view with Flash Builder Burrito preview.  Has anyone run into this and if so is there a work-around besides dropping back a version?

**Update 02 19:29**
This did not occur in previous Hero builds, e.g 18623.  I am using the default Spark theme, nothing else particularly special.

**Update 01 19:15**

I tracked down the problem to an instance of a custom (default custom, i.e the result of doing new->component based on AdvancedDataGrid) on the same form.

The component declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

The custom component instantiation.  Note "fo" is a namespace representing the path to the package for which the custom component resides.

```
<fo:adgTest width="300" height="200">
    <fo:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="blah1" />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="blah2" />
    </fo:columns>
</fo:adgTest>
```

It turns out that this custom version of AdvancedDataGrid causes the design view to break down.  Very odd.

**Update 03 2011-02-11 13:36**
A custom AdvancedDataGrid does not cause design-view breakdown unless I add columns to it.

**Update 04 2011-02-11 15:13**
Filed as a bug: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-29507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is not the problem of sdk. Its a problem of the designer (Flex Burrito). I have exactly the same envoirment, and my version of burrito is 287807.
My AdvancedDataGrit does NOT flicker!

Do you have some styles applied or something else?
After following your steps described in your question, i also have a flickering custom AdvancedDatagrid on my stage. When i click to another component (tab) and go back to the implemented adg, the flickering stops. 
When i close the Component with the flicker adg in it and open it again, the adg flicker again.

With the preversion of the sdk the adg doesn't flicker. I notice also, that the graphic is different.
In the preversion, i can see some folderIcons wirh teh expanded or closed arrows.
After switching to 19786 the foldericons disapear and the flickering starts.

There is something wrong and i would start a thread in adobe bug base.

In my opinion, you did nothing wrong. There is no better way and it is equal if i drag the custom ADG or code it in codeview. The result is always a flicker adg in designview.

Sorry for the misunderstands and my bad english
BR Frank

Comment: I am using the default Spark theme, nothing else particularly special.  I had no flicker in Burrito with the last build of the Hero SDK (build 18623) or any before it.

Comment: okay, sorry, this was a misunderstand. If you want, i can just, try, if my adg flickers also. i would open a ticket in adobe bugbase

Comment: Sure.  If it flickers for you with the new SDK then I will definitely open a bug in Adobe's JIRA.

Comment: No, sorry, all works fine with that version of sdk. I swith my sdk to Flex 4.5.19786, restart the burrito. In my existing AIR project, I', clicking on my component, wich contains an adg and switch to design view. the global style is also spark. But nothing flicker. sorry

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Yeah I noticed now its something wrong with that specific app.  Components do not get the blue selection rectangle like they should.  So whatever is causing that is probably indirectly resulting in the ADG flicker.

Comment: all right, so no problem, when dragging the adg in a new project and open the design few? BR Frank

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand your last comment, could you re-phrase the question?  Also, I updated the main question, the flicker seems to be caused by controls subclassing AdvancedDataGrid (even the most basic plain type).  I would appreciate if you could verify that.  It seems like a definite bug to me at the moment, unless I am instantiating the custom control in the wrong way.  *A custom AdvancedDataGrid does not cause flicker unless I add columns.*

Comment: I understand, the flicker is caused in a special project and i want to know, if your adg doen't flicker, if you drag it into a blank project. However forget my comment. Can you please tell me, what steps do you exactly do to produce the error? I create a new component based on group and drag an adg to the stage. flat or tree? how do you add rows?

Comment: Hey Alan. A bad day for me. Also please ignore my comment above. In your edited post, you describe what you do and yes, my adg also flicker in design view. More in my edited post

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the update and help isolating the issue; its definitely a bug with the new SDK.  I will file a report @ Adobe.  Btw, no need to apologize for some small spelling mistakes; I'm sure your English is way better than most native-English speaker's command of your native language :-)

Comment: thanks ;-) Let me know, if you have news from adobe. I'm also interested on a solution. Frank